# Python concatenate issue

Tags: python, concatenation

I have an issue with a concatenation in a script.
I have two variables:

```
fileName = 'www.blah.com/var/www/vhosts/www.blah.com/web/images/stories/?{-jYi?'
signature = '{HEX}php.nested.base64.503'
```

When I'm trying to concatenate those two variables. The result is strange:

```
files = files + '%s -> %s' % (fileName,signature) + '\n'
## Result:
 -> {HEX}php.nested.base64.503 ts/www.blah.com/web/images/stories/?{-jYi?
```

### Edit:

What I'm doing wrong?
I tried with join and I have exactly the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

For an unknown reason I don't know why when I'm printing the result on my terminal I have this result but in my sent email everything is OK.

It was a stupid question...

Comment: what is the value in `files` before concatenating

Comment: You are not using that code to get that result. Please update your post with the updated code, it's kind of hard to help without it. Also please specify the desired result.

Comment: That is indeed very odd, just ran that code and it produces the correct result, at least in the python REPL

Comment: I created files like that -> files = ''

Comment: Can you please post the updated code? It's not possible to get that result with those statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not give that result. 
However, here an alternative way:

```
files = '%s %s -> %s\n' %(files, fileName, signature)
```